# Приведение типов java (Arrays.asList ->List )

Tags: java

Допустим есть следующий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Integer[] mass = {1, 8, 9, 12, 15, 14, 17, 13};
List<Integer> r = Arrays.asList(mass);
  System.out.println(r.get(3));
  System.out.println(r.remove(3));

}
```

`r.get(3)` возвращает какое-то значение а `r.remove(3)` кидает

```
UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove
```

`r.getClass().getName()` возвращает `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`

Насколько я понял метод `asList` класса `Arrays` возвращает экземпляр внутреннего класса `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` который имплементит `List`
метод `get` вроде нормально там реализован а метод `remove` перевызывает `remove` у  `AbsttactList` который кидает данное исключение.

Как можно  из массива получить экземпляр нормального  `Arrayslist` или `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте объявить `r` как `ArrayList` вместо `List`. При этом создав новый экземпляр `ArrayList` через конструктор `ArrayList(List list)`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList(mass) );
```

Comment: так пробовал - ClassCastException

Comment: а вы уверены что `asList` именно `ArrayList` возвращает и сможет его привести к нему?

Comment: @Grundy, да, не всё учёл. И правил ответ как раз в момент публикации вашего)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, кстати вопрос-то старый 8-го года еще, я дума они уже что-то сделали более интересное за это время

Comment: @Grundy, куда уж интереснее - вон там и так, без оборачивания в `ArrayList` изменения в массиве отображаются в полученном `List`-e)

Comment: ну как я понимаю это как раз логично, потому что возвращается не новый объект, а какой-то враппер над массивом, а так как в массиве нельзя удалить элемент, то и тут типа нельзя, вроде так

Comment: @Grundy, ну, коли так оно и есть то да - логично)

Comment: Да, так работает спасибо, не увидел в доках что есть конструктор принимающий другую коллекцию

Comment: @ketchyn, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вообще крайне странно почему методом Array.asList() нельзя возвращать полноценный List,

Comment: @ketchyn, ну, это к разработчикам вопрос) А вообще можно и из этого какую-нить пользу извлечь - лист изменяется этот вслед за массивом... Можно всяких прикольных штук придумать... А так то я с вами согласен - та ещё странность)

Comment: 1) Не обязательно объявлять `ArrayList` вместо `List`. 2) В описании метода `asList` чёрным по белому написано: Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. **fixed-size** буквально означает **фиксированный размер**. В такой список нельзя ни добавить, из него нельзя и удалить. Честно же предупредили.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему вам поможет ответ из [аналогичного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)

```
new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))
```